# MultiTask in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, multitasking

As the code comment asking. I don't know why the main thread waiting for "continuation.Result" had value before print out its value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task<string> antecedent = Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith<string>(x => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("return in task1 {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        return DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
    });
    
    Task<string> continuation = antecedent.ContinueWith(x => 
    {
        x.Wait(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("return in task2 {0}{1}",Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,x.Status);
        return "Today is " + antecedent.Result;
    });

    Console.WriteLine("this will print before the result");

    Console.WriteLine(continuation.Result); //why this waiting ?

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know why the main thread waiting for "continuation.Result" had value before print out its value.

What else would you expect it to do? It cannot print a value *before* it has it.

[Task.Result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=net-5.0) internally awaits the task:

> Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete